# R Plotly: Interactive Map: How to change the presets of slider

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I created a choropleth map using plotly's plot_geo function and added a slider to cycle through different years.
How can I set the slider to a different default position?
In my example, I would like the slider to be at 2005 as the default, so that the user can cycle backwards instead of forward.

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(rep(2000,5), rep(2001,5), rep(2002,5), rep(2003,5), rep(2004,5), rep(2005,5)),
                 stat=rep(c(4,5,6,7,3,4), 5),
                 location=rep(c("DEU", "BEL", "FRA", "ITA", "SWE", "FIN"),5))

plot_geo(df, frame=~year) %>% 
  add_trace(locations=~location, z=~stat, color=~stat) %>%
  layout(geo=list(scope="europe"))
```

Comment: For your example try `%>% animation_slider(active = 5)`

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/sliders/attributes.js) for a description of animation_slider's attributes.

Comment: Thank you Tim-TU! That puts the slider to the correct position, but the plot still shows the data from the first year, not that of the last one. How can I fix that?

Comment: The problem is already known, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086856/r-plotly-animation-initial-frame) post.